# How to override info.phtml?

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to override the

> magento/module_customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml

This page:

[image]

My code for layout in

> view/frontend/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="dashboard.info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">vendor_notifications::account/dashboard/info.phtml"</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

In `/templates/account/dashboard/` I have created the `info.phtml`

I have executed `setup:di:compile` and cache clean, but it did not work, what I'm doing wrong ?

[I have followed this tutorial:](https://webkul.com/blog/override-phtml-file-magento2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_info" template="SR_MagentoCommunity::account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Also make sure, your module load after **Magento_Customer** module. For that you need to add sequence in module.xml.

Ex:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="SR_MagentoCommunity" setup_version="2.0.2">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: how can i change the sequence ?

Comment: Check updated answer. Dont forget to run 'setup:upgrade' command

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method you can override this way.

GO to your applied theme and create override

> Magento_Customer/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml

Answer (score 0):

The name of your referenceBlock is not correct.

The name must me be the same as in the vendor folder. If you go to the customer_account_index.xml file you will find that the name of the block is:

```
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="Magento_Customer::account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

Use this name instead of dashboard.info

Youre file name needs to be the same as the file of Magento: customer_account_index.xml

Comment: The reference block need be: customer_account_dashboard_info ?

Comment: Yes that's correct so your line is: <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_info">